# Как подключить Android телефон к AndroidStudio Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, mobile

Все сделал согласно [этой инструкции](http://www.rebelcode.ru/android/podklyuchenie-realnyx-android-ustrojstv-v-android-studio-i-eclipse/)...

Подключаю через usb свой HTC и появляется такое сообщение

> Unable to mount Android Phone,

а потом еще такое окно

> Unable to open a folder for Android Phone

а потом такое

> Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.

и конечно же Android Studio не видит подключения...

lsusb выводит:

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:670b Microdia
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: надо посмотреть `lsusb`

Comment: Можно подробнее, куда нужно зайти?

Comment: не проще весь етот геморой заменить виндой?

Comment: набрать в эмуляторе терминала

Comment: aleksey@aleksey:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: вот так написал после ввода lsusb

Comment: Впишите это в вопрос, в комментах плохо видно

Comment: В списке телефона не видно, проверьте кабель. Бывает питание проходит, а данные нет. Телефон сообщает о подключении к компьютеру?

Comment: Как только я подключаю телефон, телефон информирует о том, что включен режим USB отладки, потом на компьютере открывается форма в которой написано Unable to mount Android Phone. Couldn't find matching udev device.

Comment: Все получилось))) Заработало!! Спасибо!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Откройте эмулятор терминала и наберите:

```
lsusb
```

С телефоном и без телефона и найдите разницу. Если разницы нет, либо дело в кабеле, либо в настройках смартфона. В моём случае это строка:

```
Bus 002 Device 045: ID 0bb4:0c03 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)
```

Первую группу цифр (0bb4) следует вставить вначале в `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

Затем в `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` с префиксом 0x. Некоторые значения `adb` знает сам, тогда вторая строка может не понадобиться, но мешать не будет:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2207
0x0bb4
```