# Ubuntu не видит Android телефон

Tags: android, ubuntu

Ubuntu не видит телефон ZTE Nubia Z5s mini.
Команда lsusb также не выводит новых устройств.
Отладка по USB в телефоне включена.

```
root@votan-N53SN:/etc/udev/rules.d# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: У меня дома 14.04. Руководствовался следующей ссылочкой:
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/device.html .
Плюс поэксперементируй с выбором как подключать телефон: как камеру, как накопитель

Comment: Походу напал на след, при подкл к компьютеру, телефон тоже не видит пк, и нет выбора как его подключать (как камеру или как накопитель)

Comment: Я ,конечно плохой программист, но все же, банальности в духе порт или провод поменять ты уже проверил?

Comment: Возможно поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476130/130

Comment: По ссылке все делал, порты у ноутбука все перетыкал.

Comment: Может есть какое либо приложение или виджет, который может поменять режим подключения.

Comment: Была такая же проблема с Samsung. Дело оказалось в изношенном разъеме телефона и кабеля. Решилось заменой кабеля на новый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло включить mtp-режим приложение https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.vincze.usbsettings

Но если lsusb не покажет новых подключений, приложение вряд ли поможет. Меняйте кабель.